# email last lines from a text file in python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to set up an email function that will email the last 15 lines of a results.txt file in python. I am not sure how to do this and was asking do I have to connect to an email server or does python have some other way of sending email. The code below is what i have got so far and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import smtplib  

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
fp = open('/home/build/result.txt', 'r')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

me = 'name@server.com'
you = 'name@server.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % '/home/build/result.txt'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Hello again,

When I'm trying to connect the server will not connect. I know I should not enter the email address. Can anyone suggest what way to write the host information. Thanks

```
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way for your machine to send mail without connecting to a server (otherwise how would the mail get out of your machine?).  Most people have a readily available SMTP server provided for them, either by their company (if this is on an intranet) or by their ISP (if a home user).  You would need the host name (often something like smtp1.myispdomain.com where of course myispdomain is something else for you) and a port number, usually 25.  Sometimes the host is provided as a numeric IP address, like 192.168.0.1.

The `SMTP()` call can take these parameters and will connect to the server automatically.  If you don't supply the parameters when you create the SMTP object, you have to call `connect()` on it later, supplying the same info.  See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) for more.

Note that the default is to connect to `localhost` and port 25.  This works if you're on a Linux box running its own mail forwarder (e.g. Postfix, Sendmail, Exim) but if you're on a Windows machine generally you'll have to use the address supplied by your ISP.

Answer (score 2):

```
msg = MIMEText(''.join(fp.readlines()[-15:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
msg = MIMEText("\n".join(fp.read().split("\n")[-15:]))
```

Or if you don't need blank lines at end, do like

```
msg = MIMEText("\n".join(fp.read().strip().split("\n")[-15:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this one:

http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at my [mailer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mailer/) module. It wraps the email modules in the standard library.

```
from mailer import Mailer
from mailer import Message

message = Message(From="me@example.com",
                  To="you@example.com",
                  charset="utf-8")
message.Subject = 'The contents of %s' % '/home/build/result.txt'
message.Body = ''.join(fp.readlines()[-15:])

sender = Mailer('smtp.example.com')
sender.login('username', 'password')
sender.send(message)
```